# Set intertext spacing in a cell of a table

Tags: tables, spacing, memoir, paragraphs, cell

I've tried to use `\begin{Spacing}{Factor}...\end{Spacing}` to set the intertext spacing in the cell of the following table:

[image]

However there is the unexpected vertical space between the cells.

How to fix this bug globally (i.e. without `vspace, \\` etc)?

Any similar approaches, that can set single spacing in the cell, are welcome.

N.B. `\begin{Spacing}{Factor}...\end{Spacing}` works excellent in case one wrap all the table and set `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}`. However this is not the same effect I need.

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \OnehalfSpacing* % document settings
    \begin{document}
        \begin{table} % only 2 cells need to be with a single spacing
        \centering\small
            \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{11cm}|l|} 
                \hline
                Column1&Column2&Column3\\
                \hline
                Row1 Long Title &   \begin{Spacing}{0.78}  Single spacing of the text (checked with Adobe Acrobat Pro) Long text    Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text
                        \end{Spacing}  & Some text  \\ \hline
                Row2 &  Short text  & Some text \\ \hline
                Row3 &      \begin{Spacing}{0.78}  Single spacing of the text (checked with Adobe Acrobat Pro) Long text    Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text
                \end{Spacing}  & Some text  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \normalsize
        \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue `\setSpacing{1}` instead of the environment.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}

\OnehalfSpacing* % document settings

\begin{document}

\begin{table} % only 2 cells need to be with a single spacing
\centering\small

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{11cm}|l|} 
\hline
Column1 & Column2 & Column3 \\
\hline
Row1 Long Title &
  \setSpacing{1}%
  Single spacing of the text (checked with Adobe Acrobat Pro) 
  Long textLong text   Long text   Long text   Long text   
  Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text  &
  Some text \\
\hline
Row2 &  Short text  & Some text \\ \hline
Row3 &
  \setSpacing{1}%
  Single spacing of the text (checked with Adobe Acrobat Pro) 
  Long textLong text   Long text   Long text   Long text   
  Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text &
  Some text  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer!  Your decision is perfect (& simple). Please, explain, how have you managed to know about `\setSpacing`? Almost all discussions on tex.stackexchange are about `\linespread` and  `\spacing`. The first one gives no effect, the second one leads to an error. What do you think about this strange effect of the environment `Spacing`? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\OnehalfSpacing* % document settings
\begin{document}
    \begin{table} % only 2 cells need to be with a single spacing
    \centering\small
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{11cm}|l|} 
            \hline
            Column1&Column2&Column3\\
            \hline
            Row1 Long Title & \begin{minipage}[t]{11cm}\begin{Spacing}{0.78} Single spacing of the text (checked with Adobe Acrobat Pro) Long text    Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text\end{Spacing}\end{minipage} & Some text  \\ \hline
            Row2 &  Short text  & Some text \\ \hline
            Row3 &      \begin{Spacing}{0.78}  Single spacing of the text (checked with Adobe Acrobat Pro) Long text    Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text
            \end{Spacing}  & Some text  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \normalsize
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS:Don't try to use `inner sep=0` or `outer sep =0` But a newcommand to do all this whith a fixed `\vspace` could work:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\OnehalfSpacing* % document settings
\newenvironment{mySpacing}[2]{\begin{minipage}[t]{#2}\begin{Spacing}{#1}}{\end{Spacing}\vspace{0.8\baselineskip}\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table} % only 2 cells need to be with a single spacing
    \centering\small
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{11cm}|l|} 
            \hline
            Column1&Column2&Column3\\
            \hline
            Row1 Long Title & \begin{mySpacing}{0.78}{11cm} Single spacing of the text (checked with Adobe Acrobat Pro) Long text    Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text\end{mySpacing}& Some text  \\ \hline
            Row2 &  Short text  & Some text \\ \hline
            Row3 &      \begin{Spacing}{0.78}  Single spacing of the text (checked with Adobe Acrobat Pro) Long text    Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text   Long text
            \end{Spacing}  & Some text  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \normalsize
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I Didn't used the "fixing code" in the second cell.

Comment: thank you for the answer! Your second image seems to fit the needs, but the code of your second example is the copy of the code of the first example. Yes, using `vspace` is very boring. I need global settings.

Comment: Sorry for that. I think that I had a \vspace of 0 something small just beforw the end of minipage. Try it. It will be a fixed length. No changes beeded in its value

Comment: Fixed... Sorry, I tried to copy from overleaf before and after that was Away of Keyboard